# Why is my execution not showing anything?

Tags: c, csv, execution

So here is my code that reads the diabetes csv file and it calculates the average province diabetes. When I execute in Geany nothing is shown. Why is that ?

The csv file is link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lGwmjMVhZV3jKdEQ-Fekqci-57GezlNYpRUvX1TMbHY/edit#gid=0

```
// Include libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function prototypes
void getData(FILE* fp, double* provincialAverages, double* nationalAverage, double* yearlyAverages, double* ageGroupAverages);
void calculateAverages(double* provincialAverages, double* nationalAverage, double* yearlyAverages, double* ageGroupAverages);

int main(){
    // Create file pointer
    FILE *fp;
    // Create arrays for the provincial, national, yearly, and age group averages
    double provincialAverages[4];
    double nationalAverage;
    double yearlyAverages[35];
    double ageGroupAverages[9];
    
    // Open the file
    fp = fopen("statscan_diabetes.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Call the functions
    getData(fp, provincialAverages, &nationalAverage, yearlyAverages, ageGroupAverages);
    calculateAverages(provincialAverages, &nationalAverage, yearlyAverages, ageGroupAverages);

    // Close the file
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

// Function to read the data from the file and store it in the arrays
void getData(FILE *fp, double *provincialAverages, double *nationalAverage, double *yearlyAverages, double *ageGroupAverages){
    // Initialize variables
    char line[200];
    char *token;
    double sum, count;
    int i, j;
    // Read through the file line by line
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL){
        // Tokenize each line
        token = strtok(line, ",");
        // Initialize the sum and count to 0
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        // Read through each token
        while (token != NULL){
            // Skip the first 4 tokens
            if (i < 4){
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                i++;
            }
            // Get the province, age group, and value
            else if (i == 4){
                // Check the province
                if (strcmp(token, "Ontario") == 0){
                    j = 0;
                }
                else if (strcmp(token, "Quebec") == 0){
                    j = 1;
                }
                else if (strcmp(token, "British Columbia") == 0){
                    j = 2;
                }
                else if (strcmp(token, "Alberta") == 0){
                    j = 3;
                }
                else if (strcmp(token, "Canada excluding territories") == 0){
                    j = 4;
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                i++;
            }
            // Get the year
            else if (i == 5){
                if (j < 4){
                    // Add the value to the yearly average array
                    yearlyAverages[(int)atof(token)-2015+(j*7)] += atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                else{
                    // Add the value to the national average array
                    nationalAverage[(int)atof(token)-2015] += atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                i++;
            }
            // Get the age group and value
            else if (i == 6){
                // Add the value to the age group average array
                if (strcmp(token, "35 to 49 years") == 0){
                    ageGroupAverages[j*3] += atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                else if (strcmp(token, "50 to 64 years") == 0){
                    ageGroupAverages[j*3+1] += atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                else if (strcmp(token, "65 years and over") == 0){
                    ageGroupAverages[j*3+2] += atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                }
                // Add the value to the provincial average array
                if (j < 4){
                    sum += atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
                    count++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        // Calculate the average for the provincial array
        if (j < 4){
            provincialAverages[j] = sum/count;
        }
        // Reset the counter
        i = 0;
    }
}

// Function to calculate the averages
void calculateAverages(double *provincialAverages, double *nationalAverage, double *yearlyAverages, double *ageGroupAverages){
    // Calculate the averages
    printf("Provincial Averages:\n");
    printf("Ontario: %.2f%%\n", provincialAverages[0]);
    printf("Quebec: %.2f%%\n", provincialAverages[1]);
    printf("British Columbia: %.2f%%\n", provincialAverages[2]);
    printf("Alberta: %.2f%%\n\n", provincialAverages[3]);

    printf("National Average: %.2f%%\n\n", *nationalAverage);

    printf("Yearly Averages:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 35; i++){
        printf("%d: %.2f%%\n", i+2015, yearlyAverages[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Age Group Averages:\n");
    printf("35 to 49 years: %.2f%%\n", ageGroupAverages[0]);
    printf("50 to 64 years: %.2f%%\n", ageGroupAverages[1]);
    printf("65 years and over: %.2f%%\n", ageGroupAverages[2]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I tried to figure out what went wrong but I counldnt find it.

Comment: You have tagged the wrong programming language

Comment: Do you mind sharing the OS it runs on?

Comment: While it may not be everything, an obvious problem is that the 4 "accumulators" are not initialised. This will give the floating point circuitry severe heartburn, likely to crash the program. Try initialising the variables before using their values...